# How can I insert "blend_filename" into the output node?

Tags: drivers, blend-files, command-line

One thing I often do is rendering via CLI, and I like to choose EXR format to have 32bit files ready for archive. I also like to have blender saving the jpg preview to quickly see it in OS filebrowser. But then due to my company workflow, I have to go back into blender and manually export the EXRs into 16bit TIFF files to send'em to the PS guys.

Now this could be easily automated with: compositing on, a File Output node with desired format. ...if only I could find the way to set something like *current_filename####* into the name field, rather than having all them named "image".

Is this possible?

Or are there other workarounds to have EXR *and* TIFF outputted by CLI?