# Render with CLI and **then** save image with python command

Tags: python, scripting, command-line, saving

I have this need: render with command line, with "-o" output option active, and then send a "-P" command, where into the python script I want to save again the image rendered.

So, here what I came with in a Windows batch file:

```
blender.exe -b "myFile.blend" -o "/outputPath/image##" -f %framenumber% -F EXR -x 1 -P pysave.py
```

And this works as expected. The pysave.py file on the other hand, doesn't work at all. Here's what it looks like:

```
import os
import bpy

filename = bpy.path.basename(bpy.data.filepath)
filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
filepath = bpy.path.abspath('//')
fileoutput = filepath + filename

# if filename:
    # bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = filepath + filename)

Scenename = 'Scene'
img = bpy.data.images[0] 

bpy.data.scenes[Scenename].render.image_settings.file_format = 'TIFF'
bpy.data.scenes[Scenename].render.image_settings.color_mode = 'RGB'
bpy.data.scenes[Scenename].render.image_settings.color_depth = '16'
bpy.data.scenes[Scenename].render.filepath = fileoutput
img.save_render(fileoutput)

bpy.data.scenes[Scenename].render.image_settings.file_format = 'JPEG'
img.save_render(fileoutput)
```

As you can see, I'd like to save an EXR via CLI (so i can take advantage of the placeholder / no overwrite feature) and *then* a TIFF and a JPEG in the same location. But nothing comes out.

How should I do? Thanks in advance...

Comment: From https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/render/workflows/command_line.html: Always position -f or -a as the last arguments.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to save the EXR first, even after reading multiple times. If you want 3 outputformats you can easily do that with nodes (I can help with automating that), if you want to do something in between with the EXR that affects the TIFF and JPEG output you can do that with nodes too. Mixing cli and the script seems like a weird choice to me. If you want me to notice an answer please use the '@' + 'WhatAMesh'

Comment: @WhatAMesh -f or -a at the end is not so mandatory it seems, as my .bat command line works, and even triggers the "pysave.py" script. As for the need I can point this other question I made here, that maybe was more exhaustive: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111908/how-can-i-insert-blend-filename-into-the-output-node
I know how to use output node but I'd like to not have to set it up for every scene I work on. A script sounds more elegant :)

Comment: @Lssccp You don't have to set it up for every scene as you can script it. It works pretty well for me with 10+ outputs and different formats

Comment: @batFINGER ok, that makes sense. So it seems I should send a render command within the python script, like "bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)" to have _img_ loaded, but then? And also, I might be wrong but, does it preserve the "placeholder"+"no overwrite" behaviour?

Comment: @WhatAMesh Ok, so my biggest concern is how to pass the filename into the script: I know i can send parameters, but the output file name, in the batch, is a variable too: it's an array in a loop written like so _!array[%%n]!_ (I previously load into the array a list of blend files to be rendered). Is that a parameter that can be sent into the script? or the script would get exactly the string "!array[%%n]!"